# How do I get DynamoDB autoscaling to scale down when there is no activity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, autoscaling

DynamoDB with Autoscaling enabled will not scale down when there is no activity to the table. This is because it uses a CloudWatch alarm that requires there to be activity to the read or write units consumed (depending on which type of scaling you want)

So how do I get DynamoDB to scale down when there is no activity to the table?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I came up with is to schedule a Lambda function to run once a minute that performs one trivial read or write (or both) to the table for a key that I don't care about.

I'm hoping Amazon will have a better solution for this use case in the future.